# Vagrant halt scheduling

Tags: virtualbox, shutdown, vagrant

I use Vagrant with several VMs which are dependent.

For example A has a NFS server, B is a NFS client of A, etc.

When I make a `vagrant up`, A is launch, then B, etc.

But when I make a `vagrant halt`, A is shotdown, then B fails to stop properly because it tries to umount a NFS disk which is offline.

Is their a way to reverse shutdown order?

Comment: I've never heard of such a mechanism in Vagrant - as a workaround you may shut them down manually in your order with a script :-/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Vagrant Multi-Machines](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html) option? With it you can specify two machines in the same Vagrantfile and when using `vagrant up`and `vagrant halt` will affect both.

Also take a look into [vagrant load order](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/index.html#load-order).

Comment: Yes, I use Multi-Machines, but I don't find any options to setup de shutdown order.

Comment: Look in documentation at **controlling multi-machines** : http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/index.html

You can name each configuration and you can make `vagrant up name_of_conf` and as well the `vagrant halt name_of_conf`. That way you can handle it the way you want.

Comment: I know that but my VMs are not fixed, I add/remove some of them regularly, moreover I have 10 VMs, it would be heavy to manage them that way.